# Getting the IP address of the client on an ASMX Web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I am trying to Authenticate a web service by validating the IP address of the caller. The web service is meant to be internal to the network.

and in trying to do so the HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress has a weird value like "::1"

See debug point screenshot below.

[image]

Questions :

1. Why does this not work and give the proper ip of the client?
2. Is there a better way to authenticate the Web Service for an internal client?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Why does this not work and give the proper ip of the client?

It is indeed working and you are seeing "::1" because it's a reserved loopback address for ipv6 AKA localhost or 127.0.0.1 in ipv4

### [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)

> The loopback address, 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001, may be
>   abbreviated to ::1 by using both rules.

2. Is there a better way to authenticate the Web Service for an internal client?

You have to know the difference between Authentication & Authorization, i suggest you create a new question with more details on the authentication methods that you are using in your web service

Comment: Thanks! totally makes sense (sorry for the confusion on authorization and authentication)